# Using MYSQL Triggers and Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, triggers, database-schema

I do not know how to handle my issue here and I am looking for the most practical solution. I have to track a user-id across multiple tables and I am looking at triggers and Foreign Keys to solve the initial inserts into the databases for each user. On registration, I would like to create a row in each database with the user id. That way its always an update statement when I reference it in the code.

Here is my Table Structure

```
        CREATE TABLE `authentication` (
          `userid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `fname` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
          `lname` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
          `email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
          `password` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
          `online` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          `created_at` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`email`),
          KEY `userid` (`userid`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


        CREATE TABLE `user_progress` (
          `userid` int(10) NOT NULL,
          `progress_event` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Here is an example trigger I tried to make

```
        CREATE TRIGGER user_progress_add
        AFTER INSERT ON authentication
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
          INSERT INTO user_progress (userid, progress_status)
          VALUES (NEW.userid, 'signup');
        END
```

This trigger did not work. It gives the error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1".

I guess my question is, whats wrong with my trigger? is a trigger a better idea in this case than a foreign key?

Comment: And does this work? It would help people answer your post if you describe more specifically what the problem is. Did it cause an error? If so, what was the error message? Did it do something you didn't expect? What happened?

Comment: MyISAM doesn't enforce foreign key constraints.

Comment: Did you set a DELIMITER before trying to create the trigger?